# Angularjs - how to return to previous state when a checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, checkbox

I am new to angularjs

**Html file:**

```
<div class='col-md-2 searchdisplay-col1' ng-controller="amenitiesController" style="margin-top:20px">
    <h4>Amenities</h4>
    <label ng-repeat="facilityName in facilityNames" style="display:block;">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="{{facilityName.name}}"
            value="{{facilityName.id}}"
            ng-checked=""
            ng-click="lodgeFilter($event,facilityName.id)"
        /> {{facilityName.name}}
    </label>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

App.controller('amenitiesController',['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){

```
    $scope.facilityNames = []; // Initialize array for checkboxes

    $http({method: 'GET', url: "/api/facilities.json"})
        .success(function(data, status) {

            $.each(data, function(i,f) {
                $scope.facilityNames.push({ name: f.facility.name, id: f.facility.id });
            });

        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });

    $scope.lodgeFilter = function($event, id) {
        html = "";
        $http({method: 'GET', url: "/api/location/"+location_id+".json"})
            .success(function(data, status) {
                //Some Code     
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
           });
        $("#results-display").html(html);
    }
}]);
```

**Sample Json**

```
[
    {
        "facility": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Internet"
        }
    },
    {
        "facility": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bar"
        }
    }
]
```

Now when I click on checkbox, I get expected result.But when I uncheck it remains in same state, how do I make it to go to initial state?

Comment: Use `ng-model` + `ng-true-value` & `ng-false-value` to bind some data to your checkbox and observe that particular model property in your `lodgeFilter` function. This way you'll be able to detect whether checkbox has been ticked or not and act accordingly. **A question for you:** Are you fairly new to DHTML (Javascript + HTML) programming as well?

Comment: how do i bind for each checkbox, since its in a loop? yes i am fairly new to (javascript + Html)

Comment: i cant provide plunker code, since the checkboxes are generated from json data locally, and it is not hosted on any server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "ng-model" as follows (even when the key "model" does not exist in the object):

***HTML:***

```
<label ng-repeat="value in values">
    <input 
        type="checkbox"
        ng-model="value.model"
        ng-change="someFunc($event, value.model, value.id)"
    /> {{value.id}}
</label>
```

***Controller:***

```
function MainCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.values = [
        {id:1},
        {id:2},
        {id:3}
    ];

    $scope.someFunc = function (event, active, id) {
        if ( active ) {
            alert('Change detected: '+id);
            // HTTP request code
        }
        // Some code
    };
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/Chofoteddy/8bzbD/

Comment: so on ng-change = "someFunc()" ie. when checked,i get results from json. now on uncheck, i have to go back to initial state. How to do that?

Comment: @Arun I added a validation that you can be useful.

Comment: Indeed, it is a simple way to handle the application logic

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` for your custom values to checkbox.

Have a look into this link [Checkbox](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Comment: yes i went through it, but i am confused how to assign it, since the checkboxes are in loop and i am generating it from a json data

Comment: Could you give a sample json data.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shivaraj/UP6LY/ . Go through that fiddle and tell me is that what you wanted.

Comment: In your JSON what is the previous value? Is it the unchecked value?

Comment: when i click on checkbox, new html code is generated dynamically based on json data, so when i uncheck it, the old html code should be genrated.

Comment: you went through the fiddle?